# checkbox itext - how

Tags: java, itext

I made a pdf with iText and at the moment I'm showing a booleanfield as text, stating true or false. 
Now I was thinking to change this visualisation to a checkbox. False -> unchecked / true -> checked. If it's possible of course.

I tried to google it but I get results of using active checkboxes for itext and so on. I just need a visualisation of a boolean field in the pdf document I create

At the moment I just use :

```
...
Phrase validation = new Phrase();
        validation.add(new Chunk(" Approved =  "
                + documentName.getApproved(), BOLD));
...

document.add(validation);
```

Comment: 2 downvotes an no answers ... thx.

Comment: Your question is very short, and doesn't really make sense, You need to explain a bit more what you are trying to do, what you are using, and what you have tried. The people who down voted probably should have left a comment to that effect

Comment: The qestion is short because the answer probably will be te same.  I made a pdf with itext and at the moment I'm showing a booleanfield as text, stating true or false.  Now I whas thinking to change this visualisation to a checkbox.  False -> unchecked / true -> checked.  If it's possible off course.  I can give you all the pdf in code but that doens't make much sense for this question.  I tried to google it but I get results of using active checkboxes for itext and so on.  I just need a visualisation of a boolean field in the pdf document I create

Comment: Well, right there you've already given better information, edit your answer and put that in. Stackoverflow can be pedantic about these things, it's just the way it is! And yes definitely no need for the whole pdf code, but maybe but in only the lines for the text representation, and the lines for the active one that is not what you want, I think you'll be able to change that one into what you need.

Comment: Edited to question, thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this example : [Filling out interactive forms](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=154).

It shows how ot create a form and fill some of the fields, among these, some checkboxes.

---

**EDIT** :

You can then flatten the form, making these checkboxes not interactive anymore : [Form flattening](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=122)

Another approach would be to insert a symbol depending on the boolean value. If the boolean is false, insert an [empty box](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2610/index.htm), if true, insert a [marked/ticked/checked box](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2611/index.htm).

Comment: As stated are these interactive buttons.  I just need a static checkbox that is checked or unchecked by a boolean value when I create the pdf file.  The pdf is just for reporting, nothing interactive.

Comment: @DarthBlueRay sorry, I didn't notice you wanted a non-interactive field. See my corrected answer.

Comment: Looks interesting, but al by all alot of work for just checking a box.  But at least I now know that it's possible, So thx for this info!

Comment: Creating a checkbox and then flattening the form sure is overkill. Inserting a ticked/unticked checkbox is clearly the quickest and cleanest way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Just added a ticked/unticked checkbox image depending on the boolean.  I had some troubles with the location of the image but I worked it out.  Works like a charm.  the quick and dirty way but it does the trick.